# Replace method is not replacing characters in a string

Tags: c#, string, replace

I have a method that should remove repeated characters in a string and replace j character by i character but the replacement is not working !! is there any wrong statement in my codes?

```
public string filter(string key)
        {
            string answer = "";
            string keyEdit = key;
            bool found = keyEdit.Contains('j');
            if (found)
            {
                keyEdit.Replace('j', 'i'); // Replace j character by i character 
            }
            answer = new string(keyEdit.Distinct().ToArray()); // Removing duplicate characters
            return answer;
        }
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czx8s9ts(v=vs.110).aspx "*This method does not modify the value of the current instance. Instead, it returns a new string in which all occurrences of oldChar are replaced by newChar.*" It pays to read documentation.

Comment: Just a tip. You don't have to check if string contains character.
Simply `keyEdit.Replace('j', 'i');` already doesnt replace, if the character doesn't exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just replace this line:

```
keyEdit.Replace('j', 'i');
```

with this:

```
keyEdit=keyEdit.Replace('j', 'i');
```

> Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified string in
>   the current instance are replaced with another specified string. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Obviously... I'm a beast !